# Horizontal centering of 3 flexbox items of the same width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to horizontally center these 3 items using flexbox, yet without success. They all need to be of the same width.
**HTML:**

```
 <div id="contact_flex_container">
    <div id="fb">
        <img src="img/contact/fb.png" class="contact_img">
        <h3>Title1</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="yt">
        <img src="img/contact/yt.png" class="contact_img">
        <h3>Title2</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="mail">
        <img src="img/contact/mail.png" class="contact_img">
        <h3>Title3</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#contact_flex_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.contact_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#fb {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#yt {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#mail {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I have also tried setting margin-left and right to auto for each child, justify-content to center for the container, even combined with fixed width of the container in pixels, yet nothing seems to work. To be more specific, justify-content does not seem to work at all here, whatever value I put there. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flex properties you are assigning to the flex-items make them  all as large as they can be (in this case 33% of the container).

Just remove them, then change the parent to `justify-content:center`.

```css
#contact_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center
}
.contact_img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#fb {} #yt {} #mail {}
```

```html
<div id="contact_flex_container">
  <div id="fb">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
    <h3>Title1</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="yt">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
    <h3>Title2</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="mail">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
    <h3>Title3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative**, based on the expanded requirement.

An extra wrapper is required which should be `inline-flex`.

```css
#contact_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.wrap > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.contact_img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact_flex_container">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div id="fb">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="yt">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="mail">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-5.jpg" class="contact_img">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the content of those flex items is going to be of different sizes and the only way to keep their width same is by using flex-basis and flex-grow. And then, the justify-content does not work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well that's an expansion of the question....and no, you can't maintain the size of the items the same as each other using those properties...not like that...it's not how flex-grow works. What I suspect you will need is another wrapper. Lemme think.